# Creating child OU inside another child Ou

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying to create a AD structure (non-GUI approach) and I keep getting this error:

[image: Example]

The previous commands I used are:

`New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name "Sales Gurus" -Path "DC=wsa, DC=lab"`

`New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name "Sofia" -Path "OU=Sales Gurus, DC=wsa, DC=lab"`

Comment: Can you try using the full path such as: `New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name "UserAccounts" -Path "DC=FABRIKAM,DC=COM"`. Also, you can always open ADAC and witness what commands and what arguments it uses for PowerShell, through the GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you have a path issue. You create these two OUs:

```
OU=Sales Gurus, DC=wsa, DC=lab
OU=Sofia, OU=Sales Gurus, DC=wsa, DC=lab
```

Then try to create

```
OU=Supervisors, OU=Sofia, DC=wsa, DC=lab
```

That path is missing "OU=Sales Gurus" when compared to the previous paths created. Your command of:

```
New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name "Supervisors" -Path "OU=Sofia, DC=wsa, DC=lab"
```

Should include the Sales Gurus OU as well like this:

```
New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name "Supervisors" -Path "OU=Sofia, OU=Sales Gurus, DC=wsa, DC=lab"
```

Comment: Yeah I didn't know how the syntax should be formed...Thanks a lot!